# Is there an upside down caret character that I can use in Objective C?

Tags: ios

I am adding sort option to column in my table view controller based on touching the header. Do you think the best solution is adding images to my project and using them for upside/downside arrows?

Comment: How do you get those images in Objective C with character encoding?

Comment: Look at a Unicode chart.

Comment: Great! Thanks, now I learnt how it works! :)